# Unbalanced training samples for binary classification (90% vs 10%) - Tensorflow

Tags: deep-learning, logistic-regression, loss-function

I have a training sample of 100,000 (with 5 features) (90,000 classified as '0' and the rest classified as '1')

I am getting the 98% accuracy but precision/recall rates were 55%

Any suggestion to improve precision/recall rates? using tensorflow

```
#Loss function after sigmoid applied on yy_
loss = tf.losses.log_loss(yy_, scores, scope="loss")
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
prediction = (scores > 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Tensorflow but here is my suggestion

1. Don't use `accuracy` as a metric when you have imbalanced data. Instead use `confusion matrix`
2. Do hyperparameter tuning on `learning_rate`
3. If you are too much concerned about positive class, then use metrics like `Precision, Recall, F1 score`. Also you can try `ROC` & but you can also use these parameters even if you are not much concerned about positive values since these values will give some sense about how your model is behaving.
4. Do proper handling of `missing values` & standardise the data if required.
5. Remove duplicates from the data
6. `No Free Lunch` .i.e., there is no fixed algorithm which will solve all the problems. You have to try out different models. Try with various featurizations etc. Also make sure that you are leaking the data
7. Do `Feature Engineering` wherever its possible. This is the most import part